Remember tree-view collapse state
Is there a way update tree data without changing collapsibleState of the tree items?
Essentially, is there a way detect if current tree item is collapsed or not before replacing it?

is this an extension development question? if so, use the vscode-extensions tag

I think the onDidChangeTreeData does it already (you are not supposed to "replace" tree item, you edit it and then call onDidChange and then this portion of the tree re-renders, with the collapsed/uncollapsed state kept)

@defaultUsernameN onDidChangeTreeData replaces entire tree structure with new data, it doesn't "update" existing data, right? I can't find a way to "update" the existing data already shown in the tree without changing collapsibleState property of the items

Can't check right now, but I believe when I was playing with it, changing the data in the TreeDataProvider at least did not reset the whole tree for me (as in, I had at least some nodes keep their collapsed/uncollapsed state without me doing anything intentionally). Don't remember if that applied to exactly the node I was editing the data for, though, sorry.

@defaultUsernameN it seems if  collapsibleState property is not present in the data, it defaults to "collapse" for new groups, but preserves current state for existing groups. Not quite what I'm after..

Not super sure what is your desired result (are you adding new nodes and want them to be uncollapsed?...) but just in case that helps: I don't have access to my project rn, but I believe this or something very similar was what I almost copypasted to get me my desired behaviour (mine was -  rename the item visually in the file tree to [SOMEPREFIX_oldfilename] without actually doing it to the file)

Mine did not do anything un-user-friendly with the collapsing. I had the file tree, after I did my command I had the same filetree with changed names, keeping collapsed/uncollapsed state... but I was always changing the "leaf" nodes (as in the actual file, not folder), so can't vouch for what would have happened with its children
